# Isomorphisms between $\mathrm{Aut}$ of vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, automorphism-group

If we have an isomorphism $\phi: V \to W$ of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces, $\mathbb{F}$ a field, this induces an isomorphism $\hat \phi: \mathrm{Aut}(V) \to \mathrm{Aut}(W)$ by "conjugation" ($\hat \phi(\psi):=\phi\psi\phi^{-1}$ for every $\psi \in \mathrm{Aut}(V)$). Is every isomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}(V) \to \mathrm{Aut}(W)$ of this form?

Comment: Do you mean every isomorphism *of groups* $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \to \operatorname{Aut}(W)$?  Or possibly, every isomorphism of "groups $G$ with a homomorphism $\mathbb{F}^* \to G$"?

Comment: Hmm, if it's just an isomorphism of groups, then if $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$ and $V = W$ is one-dimensional, then every $\hat\phi$ is the identity, whereas we have a non-identity automorphism of complex conjugation on $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \simeq \mathbb{C}^*$.  At this point, I'm unsure of isomorphisms $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \to \operatorname{Aut}(W)$ preserving the distinguished map from $\mathbb{F}^*$ into each.